# Apache Camel AWS: HTTP request: connect timed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel

I've recently experienced an error with a camel, aws and java stack that showed me the worst stack trace I have ever seen. I decided to make an SO post to share in the case anyone else ever stumbled on this:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outgoingEndpoint': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: aws-s3://intuit-commerce-results?accessKey=xdeleteAfterRead=true&region=us-west-2&secretKey=RAW(y) due to: Unable to execute HTTP request: connect timed out`

Despite the secret id and secret key being taken out (for security reasons), the URL is perfect. Why does Camel/AWS SDK provide such a horrible stack trace? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you need to upgrade the camel-aws artifact to 1.11 instead of 1.10. It will work with the rest of camel-core and will provide much more descriptive stack traces. To get the 1.11 sdk, switch your maven configuration (or any config for that matter) to be like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Be sure to keep camel-core at its original version within your stack.